# f# set a calling interval on a function after some delay

Tags: f#, setinterval

I've some routine that I want to repeat calling every 24 hours, how can this be done in F#

```
module Program 

let private someRoutine =
    printfn "someRoutine"


let setInterval = 
     printfn "repeating"
     someRoutine.  // call repeatedly every 24 hour
```

**My Attempt**

```
Task.Delay 1000 setInterval
```

Comment: Can you show your attempts so far and what difficulties you've had with them?

Comment: I'm trying to use `Task.Delay 1000 setInterval` while also looking at http://www.fssnip.net/ln/title/Set-timeout-or-cancel- whose lengthiness doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: setInterval is not a function.  It has no parameters.

Comment: If you want to run something every 24 hours, you should probably use `cron` or a similar tool, rather than a thread sleeping for 24 hours...

Comment: @TomasPetricek the context is for renewing access tokens which expire and want to have a separate interval for renewing it. Question is this out of idiomatic world of functional programming?

Comment: Whatever API you use (FB, Google, Owin etc.) should provide for this. Unless of course you're building some API yourself....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "out of idiomatic world of functional programming".

The example you cite is using `Mailboxprocessor` with a cancellation token. It covers a general use case and probably can be adopted to your needs.

There is a [Timer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.1) which you might find useful. See the examples there.

Here's timer that sleeps for 5 seconds then prints out the time:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let timer = new Timers.Timer(5000.)
    let event = Async.AwaitEvent (timer.Elapsed) |> Async.Ignore

    printfn "%A" DateTime.Now
    timer.Start()
    printfn "%A" "A-OK"
    while true do
        Async.RunSynchronously event
        printfn "%A" DateTime.Now

    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

> λ .\AsyncTimer2.exe
>   2018/03/11 10:35:24
>   "A-OK"
>   2018/03/11 10:35:29
>   2018/03/11 10:35:34
>   2018/03/11 10:35:39
>   2018/03/11 10:35:44
>   2018/03/11 10:35:49